# How to run magento project in phpeclipse?

Tags: magento, phpeclipse

I want to include and run magento project in phpeclipse.How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, PHP-Eclipse is "on going" development. and not compatible with Magento yet, you might just open file by file. But you can debug it with [xDebug](http://www.phpeclipse.com/wiki/Howto/XDebugAndPHPEclipse).

[Example Working Magento with Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtNPk.jpg)

Comment: Can you please tell then what IDE would i use to debug magento project?

Comment: I think for Windows Notepad++ might be a good one. and for Mac, textmate would be the good one. (it's for the free version) for pro version you can try www.zend.com/en/products/studio/

Comment: correcting textwrangler is the free one. you must buy textmate to test it. ^^

Answer (score 0):

I am using PHPEd. http://www.nusphere.com/products/index.htm
Works great with magento.